# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist using SparkML

Tags: scala, linear-regression, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I am using Spark with Scala for time series analysis. I have a dataset taken from a Cassandra database that looks like this:

```
scala> train.printSchema
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- vx: double (nullable = true)
 |-- speed: double (nullable = true)
```

I tried Linear Regression as shown like [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression) just to see how it works.

```
scala> val lr = new LinearRegression().
 |   setMaxIter(10).
 |   setRegParam(0.3).
 |   setElasticNetParam(0.8)
scala> val lrModel = lr.fit(train)
```

However, I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.sca
>   la:266)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.sca
>   la:266)   at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:265)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:40)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predic
>   tor.scala:51)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:82
>   )   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:144)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:100)   ... 66
>   elided

It seems that I have to use `VectorAssembler` to create feature columns containing the predictors,

```
scala> val assembler = new VectorAssembler().
 |   setInputCols(Array("timestamp","speed")).
 |   setOutputCol("features")
scala> val output = assembler.transform(train)
```

but it throws error `TimestampType is not supported`.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type TimestampType is not
>   supported.   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$transformSchema$1.appl
>   y(VectorAssembler.scala:121)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$transformSchema$1.appl
>   y(VectorAssembler.scala:117)   at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scal
>   a:33)   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transformSchema(VectorAssembler
>   .scala:117)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transform(VectorAssembler.scala
>   :54)   ... 66 elided

If I leave out timestamp and use only one column in the `VectorAssembler`, it again throws an error. See below,

```
scala> val assembler = new VectorAssembler().
     |   setInputCols(Array("speed")).
     |   setOutputCol("features")
scala> val output = assembler.transform(train)
scala> val lrModel = lr.fit(output)
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist.   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.sca
>   la:266)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.sca
>   la:266)   at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)   at
>   scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:265)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkNumericType(SchemaUtils.scala:71
>   )   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predic
>   tor.scala:53)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:82
>   )   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:144)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:100)   ... 66
>   elided

I don't know why it says  `Field "label" does not exist` when I input `speed` alone as predictor. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define which column/columns to use as features and class label. If multiple columns are used as features then the use of `VectorAssembler()` is appropriate, as you have done. Otherwise, simply using the `setFeaturesCol()` method with the column name is enough. Note that the input column here must contain vectors and cannot be doubles.

For the class label (which class it belongs to), you can use `setLabelCol()` to define which column to use. In your case, as the `timestamp` and `speed` columns are predictors I would assume the `vx` column is the label.

To use the timestamp you could simply convert it to Unix epoch time;

```
df2 = df.withColumn("unix_time", unix_timestamp(df("timestamp")))
```

which will give you the time in seconds since January 1, 1970.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi thanks. I did it like this, `val lr = new LinearRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8).setFeaturesCol("speed").setLabelCol("vx")` and when i fit it  `lrModel = lr.fit(trainData) `, it throws error of vector type `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column speed must be of
type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually DoubleType.` how do i convert this column speed to vector UDT type.

Comment: @DhivyaNarayanasamy Missed that the column type was double. The easiest way would be to continue to use the `VectorAssembler` as you did before. Alternatively, you could use an `UDT` to convert the column.

Comment: @DhivyaNarayanasamy Updated the answer somewhat. Hope it helped you!

Comment: HI i got the answer doing like this ` val tr = output.withColumn("label", output("vx")).select("features", "label")` . Thank you.

Comment: @DhivyaNarayanasamy accept the answer if it helped you